# Android parse Json array of Strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

How can I parse in Android a Json array of strings and save it in a java string array ( like: xy[ ] ) ?

My Json to be parsed :

```
 [
  {
    "streets": [ "street1", "street2", "street3",... ],
  }
 ]
```

Later in my code I want to populated with that array a spinner item in my layout.
Everything i tried enden with only one street item listed in the spinner.

Comment: You mean array of array of Strings??

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: Actually its an array of objects of arrays of strings

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To parse

```
try {

   JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("Your json string");
   JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jr.getJSONObject(0);
   JSONArray st = jb.getJSONArray("streets");
   for(int i=0;i<st.length();i++)
       {
      String street = st.getString(i);
      Log.i("..........",""+street);
      // loop and add it to array or arraylist
        }
}catch(Exception e)
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Once you parse and add it to array. Use the same to populate your spinner.

`[` represents json array node

`{` represents json object node

Comment: @Hesam then you are doing it wrong not because the parsing code posted is wrong

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I have and array exactly like question and Array contains 5 urls. I did your way, the Intelij Idea is saying "Variable 'url' initializer '(String) jFaceShape.get(j)' is redundant". Also, when I compile I can see my loop but no string is inside. This is my code: JSONArray jFaceShape = jObject.optJSONArray(Product.TAG_FACE_SHAPES); for(int j=0; j<jFaceShape.length(); j++) {
String url = (String) jFaceShape.get(j);
Log.d(TAG, "url => " + url);}

Comment: @Hesam post your json. you are doing it wrong. It should work irrespective of the IDE that you use

Comment: I appreciate a lot for your time man. Please look at this url http://www.hijab2go.com/?route=feed/web_api/products

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51390/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-hesam)

Comment: It was my problem. the code works fine. Sorry for wrong message!

Comment: @Raghunandan But what if I dont know if the json is array or object with a key to point to array ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir you can check if the json is a json object or a json array

Comment: @RoyiNamir `if (json instanceof JSONObject)` it's a json object else a json array

Comment: @RoyiNamir that is your json it can be a json object or a json array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61354/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-royi-namir).

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
 JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(json string);

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){

            JSONObject c = arr.getJSONObject(i);        
            JSONArray ar_in = c.getJSONArray("streets");

        for(int j = 0; j < ar_in.length(); j++){    
            Log.v("result--", ar_in.getString(j));
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

We need to make JSON object first. For example,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resp);
// resp is your JSON string
JSONArray arr  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
Log.i(LOG, "arr length =  " + arr.length());
for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
{...
```

arr may contains other JSON Objects or JSON array. How to convert the JSON depends on the String. There is a complete example with some explanation about JSON String to JSON array can be found at http://www.hemelix.com/JSONHandling